# problem with bitcoin software

Tags: transactions

My following bitcoin comes up with errors which are saying "Wallet (out of sync) and also Recent Transactions (out of sync)"

Is this consistent throughout and will go away or is there a problem?

The port number is currently set as 9050

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's either downloading the blockchain or reindexing the blocks on disk. There should be a progress bar at the bottom.